# Why is there a Stack Overflow in Portuguese but not in other languages?

Tags: discussion, split-stack-overflow, portuguese-stack-overflow

I don't understand why there's a version of [Stack Overflow in Portuguese.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

I find the idea great, because it allows non-English speakers to ask for help or contribute, but why only in Portuguese? Why is there no French, German, Italian, ... version?

Comment: Other language SO sites are coming.

Comment: @JonasCz Do you have info ?

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to the [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).SO, there is already a  [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).SO, a [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/).SO, and a [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).SO.

New sites have to be proposed at [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), then once they reach full commitment they are usually launched to beta sites. However, since different languages cause the team to need to do extra speciality language programming things, even if a foreign language site reaches full commitment, it'll still take week/months for the beta site to launch.

For example, [German](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54232/stack-overflow-in-german).SO and [Turkish](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish).SO have already reached full commitment, and is just waiting for the devs/higher-ups to make sure they can get everything working OK before launching.

To search for other SO proposal sites in other languages, just go to [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) and search for stack overflow.

Comment: Translations are not the only obstacle - a good community manager fluent in the language is also needed.

Comment: Why is there no American site?   :)

Answer (score 5):

You are incorrect in saying there is only the Portuguese Stack Overflow localized site.

We have [Japanese Stack Overflow](http://ja.stackoverflow.com) and [Russian Stack Overflow](http://ru.stackoverflow.com) at this time, and will be adding more, mostly depending on getting qualified community managers and translations for those languages.