# How should we deal with extremely poor English?

Tags: discussion, languages

What is the preferred way to deal with questions phrased in extremely poor English? I'm not talking about spelling mistakes, but rather glaring grammatical errors and sentence structures that make you think that a Markov-Chain-gone-rogue would have created it.

I have thought about several possibilities, each with their own merit:

### 1. Flag the question as "Unclear what you're asking"

This is currently my prefered method. It accurately describes the problem with the question and should - in theory - put the question on hold and give the original poster an incentive to either give Google Translate a shot or, even better, ask someone who speaks both their native language and English.

On the other hand, this might cause the original poster to "give up" trying to get answers on Stack Overflow and generally perceive the site and community as unwelcoming.

### 2. Attempt to edit the question

Another way could be to attempt and guess what the original poster was trying to say and edit the question at hand to correct English spelling and grammar.

While this is certainly "more friendly" and helpful for the original poster, it might just as well miss the point completely and end up changing the question completely, depending on how well the editor "guessed" the intent of the original poster.

### 3. Post a comment asking for clarification

This may or may not work. Comments do not have the same authoritive gist about them as a big, yellow "On Hold"-sign and as such the original poster may or may not feel compelled to try harder in forming an actually understandable question.

---

Is there an agreed-upon way on how to react to such questions?

Comment: Always post a comment asking for clarification. When you can, edit. When it's impossible to edit without a significant risk of getting it wrong, flag/vote to close (> 3k rep).

Comment: So, edit if possible. Comment otherwise. Flag if you have no chance. ?

Comment: Yes, except that I'd always comment. The user needs the feedback, the learning effect, and to check whether the edit is still saying what they want to say.

Comment: If you write that as an answer, I'd gladly upvote and accept it

Comment: _"... give the original poster an incentive to [...] give Google Translate a shot"_ I wouldn't be surprised if a lot of these questions actually come via Google Translate.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser This likely stems from the fact that Google Translate is good at translating small sentences like "I want to buy a car" and not whole paragraphs from Hindi to English. People are just very bad at using translation software.

Comment: Votes work differently on meta, @DavidStockinger. They do not affect your reputation and are used to express (dis)agreement, not assessment of post quality.

Comment: @Justastudent Ahh, I was wondering why good posts on meta have something like -75 downvotes

Comment: [How soon should I vote to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026/159251)

Comment: Consider that many non-native English speakers have no alternative than to try themselves on StackOverflow. And they come with a problem, possibly in their profession. So their problems are more severe than _"how can I find calls made by java.reflection"_. So they fall in the category of those to be accepted: loud small children and so on.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212385/translation-help-review-queue also, they're working on a mentoring system currently that could also be of help with these (can't be arsed to find a linky)

Comment: [What if the asker entered a discussion with a commenter whom also have a poor english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603435/unable-to-kill-process-with-zwterminateprocess-and-duplicated-handle). a million dollar question ladies and gentlemens (in a western texas accent)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

- Always ask for clarification.
- When you can, edit.
- When it's impossible to edit without a significant risk of getting the meaning wrong, flag or vote to close.

Always post a comment asking for clarification. The user needs the feedback, the learning effect, and to check whether the edit is still saying what they want to say.

Comment: Expanding this, #3 (Clarification) is correct, because we want to make sure the asker's question is being correctly communicated; #2 (Edit) is correct, as we want to make sure the purpose of SO as a reference for the broader community is being fulfilled; and #1 (Flag Unclear) is correct, because, in order to preserve SO's read/search-ability, we must place a burden of reasonably clear communication on askers/answerers.  This encourages motivated askers to write clear questions while discouraging "throwaways". Where to draw the line of "reasonably clear" is left as an exercise to the user.

Comment: `Where to draw the line of "reasonably clear" is left as an exercise to the user.` Not really @AndrewKozak. Even if someone incorrectly votes to close a question as unclear, it still requires four others to agree that the question is unsalvageable. Also, the first flag or close vote will indicate to the asker that there is a problem with their question that they can attempt to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @NisargShah We are saying the same thing; the user(s) reviewing the question make a determination of clarity/quality based on their own judgment.  You are correct in your statement about the subsequent processes that provide checks and balances.  My remark was a reference to common expression found in math/science textbooks.  Please consider it struck out.  Cheers~

Answer (score 8):

Let's ask [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), a page that everyone who uses the site is expected to read!

> Write a title that summarizes the specific problem
>
> Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important! Remember, this is the first part of your question others will see - you want to make a good impression. If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you.
>
> ...
>
> Proof-read before posting!
>
> Now that you're ready to ask your question, take a deep breath and read through it from start to finish. Pretend you're seeing it for the first time: does it make sense?

If a user's question doesn't comply with those simple guidelines, I'm not willing to waste my time trying to decipher their word salad just to be able to determine if (a) they actually asked a question (b) it conforms to the site's rules (c) whether it's actually answerable.

At the end of the day it's up to you to decide how much of your own time you're willing to dedicate to these users, but considering that the vast majority who post incoherent questions are help vampires anyway... well, I'm sure you have better things to do.

Addendum:

Whatever happened to "have a Stack Overflow for each country/language"? We already have https://pt.stackoverflow.com/, I'm certain that other equally specific ones - that allow the askers and answerers to communicate in their native language - would take a massive burden off those who moderate the English SO.

Comment: For those who don't have a solid understanding of the English language, these requirements aren't exactly "simple". Considering all the things that are wrong with the average question on [so], I can live with needing to rewrite a question where the only problem is poor English usage (if it's incomprehensible, that's a different story).

Comment: @Dukeling My interpretation was that the asker is talking about questions that are absolutely not decent in any way shape or form. After all, if they were decent, you wouldn't need to consider asking the person who wrote them what they meant!

Comment: @Dukeling As with any Meta question lacking concrete examples, people are free to imagine their own instances of the subject, and then disagree with each other based on their different images. Is the Meta post talking about posts with no actually discernible question/problem statement, or is it talking about questions that are just very hard to read? I thought the former, based on "glaring grammatical errors and sentence structures that make you think that a Markov-Chain-gone-rogue would have created it." but you seem to picture the latter.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The problem with bringing up concrete examples is that these examples are usually downvoted do oblivion rather quickly and thus difficult to preserve. If I find such a question in the triage queue again, I'll screenshot and add it here.

Comment: Screenshots are indeed the way to go, @DavidStockinger.

Comment: @JoshCaswell This problem is easily solved by writing answers in the form: "If X, .... If Y, ....".

Comment: [Why is there a Stack Overflow in Portuguese but not in other languages?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291183)